# How to merge 2 RGB images in DM by scripting?

Tags: image-processing, rgb, dm-script

I would like to overlay 2 (or more) RGB images in Digital Micrograph by scripting.

Unlike some realimages without color that can be merged by summing the intensity, RGB images should be merged in another way but I have no clue.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum RGB images just like regular images, but your problem is that you need to define what you mean by "overlay".

RGB Images are triplets holding a value for each of the 3 channels RED, GREEN, BLUE and these values are clipped between [0 and 255].

"Summing" RGB images will give you again a triplet, but any value bigger then 255 is truncated to 255, so you will shift more and more towards "white" in the image.

You could define an "overlay" as the mean-values instead, but the effect of "overlaying" then becomes more and more towards "average gray".

Or you could define an "overlay" as the "max-values" or "min-values" of the involved channels.

Or, or, or....

When you think of "overlaying" RGB images, it is helpful to think of other graphic programs like Photoshop which allow you combinining "layers". Usually these programs offer you multiple options ( *"overlay, screen, lighten, darken, you name it..."* ) which all define a different mathematical relationship between the three color values of the first and the three color values of the second layer.

The commands you need to do this maths are `RGB( )`, `RED( )`, `GREEN( )`, and `BLUE( )` as well as simple maths. See the example:

```
image img1r := RealImage("Red 1",4,256,256)
image img1g := RealImage("Green 1",4,256,256)
image img1b := RealImage("Blue 1",4,256,256)

img1r = icol/iwidth * 256
img1b = iradius/iwidth * 256
img1g = irow/iwidth * 256

RGBImage img1 = RGB(img1r,img1g,img1b)
img1.Setname( "Image 1 (RGB)")

image img2r := RealImage("Red 2",4,256,256)
image img2g := RealImage("Green 2",4,256,256)
image img2b := RealImage("Blue 2",4,256,256)

img2r = (icol%10)<5 ? 256 : 100
img2g = (irow%10)<5 ? 256 : 100
img2b = (iradius%10)<5 ? 256 : 100
RGBImage img2 = RGB(img2r,img2g,img2b)
img2.Setname( "Image 2 (RGB)")

image sumImg = img1 + img2
sumImg.SetName( "SUM" )

image avImg = (img1 + img2)/2
avImg.SetName( "AVERAGE" )

image maxImg = RGB( max(red(img1),red(img2)), max(green(img1),green(img2)), max(blue(img1),blue(img2)))
maxImg.SetName( "Channel MAX" )

image minImg = RGB( min(red(img1),red(img2)), min(green(img1),green(img2)), min(blue(img1),blue(img2)))
minImg.SetName( "Channel MIN" )


// Arrange display
EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages( "delete" )

minImg.ShowImage()
maxImg.ShowImage()
avImg.ShowImage()
sumImg.ShowImage()
img2.ShowImage()
img1.ShowImage()

TagGroup layout = SLMCreateGridLayout( 2 , 3 )
EGUArrangeAllShownImagesInLayout( layout )
```

[image: Output]

---

It should also be noted that some "overlay" combinations are not based on the  Red/Green/Blue ([RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)) color model, but on the alternative Hue/Saturation/Brightness ([HSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)) color model.

DigitalMicrograph scripting does natively only support RGB, but you can do the maths yourself.

You might also find it useful to look at the examples script "[Display as HSB.s](http://www.gatan.com/sites/default/files/Scripts/Display%20as%20HSB.s)" on the [Gatan script example](http://www.gatan.com/resources/scripts) site.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much! I am sorry about the lack of definition of 'overlay'. What I want to do is to achieve the 'color mix' function which is already exist in DM by scripting. I wasn't sure which mode of overlay it should be until I saw all your trials. I think the average value is used. Thank you again for all the details!

Answer (score 1):

You can script image merging very simply with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

As you have not provided any sample images, I have made a couple - `image1.png` and `image2.png` like this:

[image]
[image]

Now, there are lots of **Blend Modes** available - some of the more common ones are *Lighten*, *Darken*, *Overlay*, *Blend*. So, let's try a few at the command line in Terminal:

```
convert image1.png image2.png -compose darken -composite result.png
```

[image]

```
convert image1.png image2.png -compose lighten -composite result.png
```

[image]

```
convert image1.png image2.png -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

[image]

The options are endless - you can get a list of the blend modes available in ImageMagick like this:

```
identity -list compose
```

**Output**

```
Atop
Blend
Blur
Bumpmap
ChangeMask
Clear
ColorBurn
ColorDodge
Colorize
CopyBlack
CopyBlue
CopyCyan
CopyGreen
Copy
CopyMagenta
CopyOpacity
CopyRed
CopyYellow
Darken
DarkenIntensity
DivideDst
DivideSrc
Dst
Difference
Displace
Dissolve
Distort
DstAtop
DstIn
DstOut
DstOver
Exclusion
HardLight
HardMix
Hue
In
Lighten
LightenIntensity
LinearBurn
LinearDodge
LinearLight
Luminize
Mathematics
MinusDst
MinusSrc
Modulate
ModulusAdd
ModulusSubtract
Multiply
None
Out
Overlay
Over
PegtopLight
PinLight
Plus
Replace
Saturate
Screen
SoftLight
Src
SrcAtop
SrcIn
SrcOut
SrcOver
VividLight
Xor
```

Here are all the options:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the nice overview of different RGB overlays. Howver, I think with the tag [tag:DM-script] present, the question is aimed at the specific scripting language of DigitalMicrograph rather than general image processing.

Comment: @BmyGuest Thank you. I see your point - I just took it as needing to be done *"by scripting"* and assumed any scripting was ok, but I guess OP did mean specifically by `dm-script`. I'll leave it anyway - it may be useful to someone!

Comment: I think it is indeed useful, as it shows very nicely the point about "you need to defined what 'overlaying' means" with the large number of possibilties. A useful overview-plot.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you so much for telling me this, and yes I am actually working on Digital Micrograph scripting. But your overview is also really useful. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeyWei Pleasure! Good luck with your project :-)